# Access element inside response as object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a response from my mongodb database as the following

```
{_id: '61ca4273e7cc1da1f3dbc9a3', title: 'Hero Syndrome', slug: 'hero-syndrome', category: 'Game', release_date: null, … }
```

I'm using `Redux` to fetch the data.
When I do `console.log(game)` which is the Object I provided, the console return the Object indeed. But when I'm trying to access the children such as `title` or `slug` it doesn't work.

I used to have this error `Objects are not valid as a React child ..` but fixed it somehow randomly in the code.

**Any idea how to access `title` for example ?**

What I tried : `{title}, title, {game.title}` and none of them work

What I did to get data from Redux :

```
GameComponent.propTypes = {
  game: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  game: state.game,
});
```

And at the top of the component

```
function GameComponent({
  game: { game, loading, title },

}) { ....
```

I tried to convert the object to string and to array in order for React to read it but I failed.

Code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getGameByToken } from '../actions/game';
import GameOverview from './GameOverview';

function GameComponent({ game: { game, loading, title }, getGameByToken, auth }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    getGameByToken(token);
  }, [getGameByToken, token]);

    return <>
        //this doesn't work
    Title : {title}
    
    </>;
}

GameComponent.propTypes = {
  getGameByToken: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  game: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  game: state.game,
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getGameByToken })(GameComponent);
```

Response from database in redux :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { setAlert } from './alert';
import { GET_GAME, GAME_ERROR } from './types';

// GET GAMES BY TOKEN
export const getgameByToken = (token) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/games/' + token);

    dispatch({ type: GET_GAME, payload: res.data });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: GAME_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: err.response.msg,
        status: err.response.status,
      },
    });
  }
};
```

From Redux Dev Tools :

[image: https://i.imgur.com/6E3MESn.png]

EDIT: If I rename   `game: state.game,` to   `game: state.game.game`, I actually got the value ! But when refreshing It goes back saying `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'title')`

Comment: Do you have a link to the code? is it possible to see it?

Comment: @Gass Sure I updated the post

Comment: When you say "the console return the Object indeed" after printing, do you mean that it returns a string representing the response object, or prints `Object` ?

Comment: @AlonBarenboim Updated. The console prints in Object that have multiple strings.

Comment: @AlonBarenboim Example https://i.imgur.com/353NdIR.png